# Battery conservation?

Tags: battery-life

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-phone)

What are some general ways to improve the battery life of my phone?