# What happens when I connect a 2 amp charger instead of the 0.7 amp charger provided?

Tags: charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my phone liable to explode if I charge it with a charger that came with a different phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/is-my-phone-liable-to-explode-if-i-charge-it-with-a-charger-that-came-with-a-dif)
>   [What's the safe limit on charger output for a Galaxy Nexus](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25008/whats-the-safe-limit-on-charger-output-for-a-galaxy-nexus)

I have a phone with 0.7 amp charger. I also have a Galaxy Nexus with a 2 amp charger.  If I connect the 2 amp charger into my phone, will my phone blow up?

Comment: Usually I say "try it and see", but in this case...

Comment: @offby1 ... but in this case make sure you have a camera at hand :)

Comment: Related: [Is my phone liable to explode if I charge it with a charger that came with a different phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/is-my-phone-liable-to-explode-if-i-charge-it-with-a-charger-that-came-with-a-dif)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Electric current is measured in [Amperes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amperes), shortened to Amps or simply the letter A.

One well spread example is to think of electricity in terms of water, pressure being equivalent to voltage, and flow rate equivalent to amps. As long as you have the correct pressure, the flow rate isn't a problem, provided the necessary minimum is present.

Typically electronics will only draw the current they need, so extra amps is OK.

The important thing is having the correct voltage with sufficient amperage available. Extra amperage will be ignored by your device.