# Galaxy tab 10.1 charging with USB 3.0

Tags: usb, charging, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

When referring to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33308/samsung-galaxy-tab-charging-technique-through-usb-cable) post, it seems like the Samsung Galaxy Tab should be able to charge while connected to a USB 3.0 port while running.

I've noticed that when I have my Tablet running and plugged into a power strip, the device does gain battery rather than losing it.

However when I try to charge with my USB 3.0 in my laptop, the device loses battery life. It still charges, but the running device uses more battery than it gains from USB 3.0.

Am I doing something wrong here? I have the Samsung USB drivers installed and I am using the original Samsung cable. Perhaps there is some problems with my battery? Or am I still supposed to lose battery life while plugged into a USB 3.0?

Comment: This is nothing unusual, see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/46766/16575). While connected to different power sources, the "amount of power provided" differs, while the amount of power *used* remains the same. So charging speed differs as well, and the device might even *discharge* when you're using more power than is provided.

Comment: I'll back up what Izzy is saying. The Galaxy Tab, as a tablet, draws more power (because of its large screen) than a phone does. Some USB chipsets will provide enough power to charge it while operating, but some won't.

Comment: Shouldn't USB 3.0 be able to draw enough current to actually charge the device? That's how I interpreted from my above link.