# Will constantly having Bluetooth on drain my battery too fast?

Tags: bluetooth, battery-life

I'm thinking about making an app which will require Bluetooth to be available at all times.  However, if this reduces battery charge life significantly, then that's kind of a show stopper.  Can anyone give me a general idea about how much drain constant Bluetooth use will put on the battery?

Comment: Discoverability is definitely the killer here on Bluetooth in terms of battery.

Comment: Also related: [Does allowing Bluetooth discovery consume more power?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/does-allowing-bluetooth-discovery-consume-more-power)

Answer (score 13):

What drains... my special. Here some data samples, based on a Motorola Droid:

```
+--------------------+----------+
| Mode               | Energy   |
+--------------------+----------+
| Bluetooth receive  | 751 mW   |
| Bluetooth send     | 487 mW   |
| Bluetooth standby  |   2,8 mW |
+--------------------+----------+
```

So if you use BT quite regularly (e.g. to be able to immediately pick up a call with your headset), having it in standby doesn't hurt *that* much (Compare: 2G StandBy 11,6 mW, 3G StandBy 18,3 mW, Wifi StandBy 7,8 mW -- and, often mistaken: GPS StandBy 0,4 mW).

But if, on the other hand, you use BT once a week (or even less) -- heck, you can manually enable it then, there are enough "toggle switches" and widgets available.

Comment: @SachinShekhar If you are interested in the full list: [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device/27742#27742)

Comment: How did you get this data?

Comment: @Snekse simply follow the link in my previous comment to find out :)

Answer (score 7):

Constant use of Bluetooth will put quite a significant drain on the battery, even having it on is known to drain the battery.

Comment: It will certainly drain it faster than having it turned off.  However, how fast will vary depending on the phone.

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on what you are using Bluetooth for.  I have a Bluetooth watch ([MBW-150](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&q=mbw-150&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=4482759302556581117&ei=M1_NTIDnD8OclgeBqbWsBw&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q8wIwAA#)) that I sync with my phone using [OpenWatch](http://www.appbrain.com/app/openwatch/com.smartmadsoft.openwatch) and it affects my battery life minimally.  All it does is sync the phone's time with my watch, vibrates on certain notifications/calls, and gives me control of my music player (play/stop/next/prev/volume).  So I essentially have Bluetooth turned on all the time and haven't really seen a battery problem because of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S (Vibrant):

- With Bluetooth & Sync turned on, but the Bluetooth not connected, I better have > 45% battery before I go to bed or else my phone will be dead by morning.
- With Bluetooth & Sync turned off, I only use 1-2% battery overnight.

How much of that is Bluetooth and how much is Sync, I don't know. But the combination sure kicks the crap outta my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i recently got a wireless earphones for making calls and sometimes i turn my earphones off but forget to turn off my bluetooth on my phone. I usually found this to be a problem since i would charge my phone before gping to bed and leaving it at 50%. Before it used to last me over night but lately i been waking up to zero percent battery... so personally i don't advice you to leave bluetooth on... plus for me it cause my phone to overheat while charging.

Comment: This is exactly the style of data I wanted to know, but that is a surprisingly high drain. The truth is what I want to know, but I'd hope that the current truth is better than that! Do you know what Android version you had installed; what kind of Bluetooth hardware your phone used; and whether it was connecting to any Bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an article from Techrepublic. There is a lot of anecdotal "yes" here, but very little scientific responses. I think if you look at the actual analysis responses using hard data, you'll see that bluetooth has little impact on battery. I never turn off bluetooth on my phone and have several apps that use bluetooth, and the only time my battery doesn't last all day is when I play a game or two on it.

[10 common misconceptions about mobile device batteries](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-common-misconceptions-about-mobile-device-batteries/)

Answer (score 0):

On my Galaxy S3 even if I have bluetooth turned on but do not use it at all it still drains my battery 30% faster as opposed to if it was turned off!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Android Enthusiasts Lance! :) While your answer is valid, it would be great if you could provide some data from your experience ( if you have some time available you could screenshot the battery life screen on multiple runs with bluetooth turned off/on) :)