# Does Bluetooth drain power when it's not in use?

Tags: bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will constantly having Bluetooth on drain my battery too fast?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/will-constantly-having-bluetooth-on-drain-my-battery-too-fast)

When Bluetooth is turned on, but not in use, is it still draining power? If so, how much relative to it being in use?

Comment: @AlEverett - I saw that question, but I didn't feel it answered my question of how much of a battery drain it was while on, but not in use, relative to being on and in use.

Comment: Most of the answers there specifically address the "standby" power, and one of them even gives numbers for how much power that uses compared to transmitting. Feel free to bounty that question if you want more information than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. 
When it is on, but not in use, it continually scans for the device it has been previously paired with.

This allows for it to do things like-- automagically connect to your car when you get in it.

However, the amount of battery drain is still minimal, even if it *is* continually scanning.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know. I have my Nexus 7 set up to Bluetooth tether from my phone, so I essentially have 3G on my tablet. It didn't seem to be draining my battery any faster when it wasn't in use, but I wanted to check.