# How to optimize energy consumption during GPS tracking?

Tags: gps, battery-life, gps-tracking

Very often I use my phone and the app MyTracks or GPSTrackerLite to track my hiking/biking tours.

This really works great and I'm thrilledy by the lot of possibilities in combination with google maps, facebook etc.

However there is one problem: If I'm tracking the battery lasts only a few hours. This is enough for most hikes, but for daytrips, it isn't sufficient. Do you have any tips how to save energy? For example using plane mode? Would this decrease the energy consumption? Are there any other functions I could disable?

I'm using HTC Desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-phone/269#269) on some ways to save battery power on your  phone.

Comment: Thanks, I read it. Do you have experience with underclocking in combination with tracking? How many CPU power is necessary to ensure that GPS tracking is working correctly?

Comment: @Roflcoptr I have no experience with it, but I would think that so long as the app doesn't become unresponsive then it should be OK.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it the next time I'm going on a tour.

Answer (score 2):

I never used those tracking apps, but maybe you can decrease their polling frequency?. This will decrease the accuracy of the tracking, but generally you don't need the app to track every meter you move.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the accuracy is bad engough without decreasing the polling frequency ;) However, if the weather is very nice (and the GPS signal better) the polling frequencey could be increased.