# Is it normal for Android System to be the top battery user?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, battery, battery-life

Over the past couple of days, the battery usage of my new phone has been as follows:

> 34% - Android System
>   28% - Cell Standby
>   21% - Phone idle
>   10% - Display
>   03% - Google Goggles
>   02% - Angry Birds
>   02% - Majesty

This feels very off to me. I would have expected the games and display to rank much higher in terms of battery use. Could the high usage of Android System indicate a potential problem, or is this fairly normal?

Additional information:

I typically end up with around 15:00 hours uptime and 3:45 hours awake by the end of the day. Daily use so far includes short bursts of playing games and Internet use, but no listening to music. I haven't had a day of heavy calls/texting with the phone yet.

These numbers are all from the built in battery use screen under settings.

Comment: The battery usage meters reset each time the phone is plugged in. Was your phone unplugged for the entire 15 hours?

Comment: @Gary Comtois Yes. The above is after approximately 15 hours unplugged.

Comment: Ocasionally I notice my battery dying quicker than normal and it will show Android system as the top user. If I shut it off and turn it back on it usually fixes it. I am still not sure what is causing this though.

Comment: Those seem to be awfully high numbers for Cell Standby and Phone Idle too -- what's your signal strength like?  Being in an area with poor reception can cause your radios to use a lot of extra power.

Comment: @afrazier Reception seems decent. It varies from 1 to four (full) bars. It's good enough that I don't notice it (no dropped calls, static, etc.). Going to the details for Cell Standby, it shows that "Time without a signal" is 0%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on your usage.  Android System includes Sync, so if you're not using your phone a lot then I would assume Sync and Standby would use the most battery -- so your details make sense.

**Edit:** As per the comments, I think the battery usage is being recorded wrong.

Comment: I think I'm using my phone a fair amount. You can see Angry Birds and Majesty on the list there. I typically end up with around 15:00 hours uptime and 3:45 hours awake by the end of the day. Does that still fit with your answer?

Comment: Hmm no, I don't think that fits.  How drained is your battery after that?  I am thinking the battery use is not being tracked properly as well, what app are you using (or is it built in)?

Comment: 15:00 hours is about when the battery dies. It's a potential problem for me, since that isn't quite all day. I'm using the built in battery usage meter (settings->About Phone->Battery->Battery Use).

Comment: OK.  Well I do think the usage meter is wrong, but 15 hours is about normal without any tweaks.  I recommend the XDA forum if you want to find a custom ROM that will give you better battery life (http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=638) and you can also take a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-phone