# Battery Drain from Android OS and Android System

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-s-5, system

I've got a Galaxy S5 and recently, Android OS and Android system just seem to be draining my battery.

Not done anything extraordinary regarding rooting or anything, it's all stock.

I can only manage 2 hours screen time - 2 hours 30 if I'm lucky.

Other than running a factory reset. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [Battery draining fast because of Android System](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110588/16575) / [Why do “android system” and “androd os” take 30% battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/92559/16575) / [Why does the Kernel and Android System/Android OS drain my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114285/16575) / [Is it normal for Android System to be the top battery user?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6154/16575) / [search results](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=battery+android+system+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Might want to post the battery graph and top applications draining power.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with mine by going to **Settings**, **Battery**, and then the **Detail** button under *Save battery power by managing your apps*.

I then set pretty much everything to **Auto Stop** except for "critical" apps like my launcher, SMS, etc. - anything I want to still get notifications on.

This has significantly improved my battery life.

Answer (score 0):

As Jkubecki said; Android devices face this problem as multiple always seems to run on the back end draining your battery.
So you need to run all the unwanted application to fix this issue. It will certainly show an improvement in your battery duration.

Comment: Those apps would show up separately in the stats then, wouldn't they? If I understand the OP correctly, battery stats show "Android OS" and "Android System" as the top consumers (as in the questions I've linked from my comment on the question itself).