# How to keep my battery life?

Tags: battery, battery-life

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-phone)

Today I woke up after a night without charging my phone (galaxy s2). and he's dead, last night he was almost fully charged, what to check ? how can i avoid thids kind of issues?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest going for [Battery Monitor](https://market.android.com/details?id=ccc71.bmw.pro&hl=en) great app tells you exactly what is running the battery the most and then you can kill that process etc

Answer (score 1):

I use [JuiceDefender](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender) and [JuicePlotter](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.latedroid.juiceplotter) to conserve and monitor battery, almost doubles my battery life on Galaxy S.

Answer (score 0):

Best Option: root your phone and install some sort of CPU governor/undervolted kernel.

Things to try: Set brightness to minimum possible, turn wi-fi off, turn auto sync off or to do it only every few hours, turn data off (if not in use).

**ALSO:** I have an HTC phone, but this may work... type in *#*#4636#*#* in your dialer and call it. If it works correctly it will bring up a menu. Go into your phone information and change your preferred network type to something else (depending on what your carrier is, I use GSM Auto)