# Battery drain with in no time in Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace for almost an year now. The battery of my phone get discharged now with-in no time of charging. The battery status in Setting -> About Phone - > Battery use shown the following

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I could not interpret what does this mean.

Is there some app which is eating up the battery or I need to replace the battery? Is it normal for battery of this model?

Comment: The image does not say much without knowing how long your battery lasts now (and how long it did before). How full is it at the time of that picture? The battery symbol looks like "full" (but it contains the charge-indicator, so it's hard to say). 14.5 hours is not bad a runtime nowadays -- but of course not if you did nothing in that time. What your screenshot basically says is: The current battery drainage is shared to 50% by those components. With your battery at 98% charge, each had used ~1% of it then. If you provide the missing info we might be able to tell more.

Comment: @Izzy Can you suggest some app which can help me provide you the missing information?

Comment: Well, you should know what the battery level was at the time of your screenshot (at least roughly if you've got no percentage). Also you should know how much you were using your device in that time, and with what apps. Aside from that, check the "Related" section of this question, e.g. [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/) and [Is there any study on how which services/sensors consume the battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/), plus follow the [tag:battery-life] tag for more related questions.

Comment: Taking a look at the screenshot again: no apps, just phone? Seems to be a candidate for [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we already have a lot of related answers to similar questions, just let me sum up here:

As said in my above comment, the screenshot does not provide much information without having related details available. All it says is: The overall battery consumption after ~14.5 hours is shared 50:50 by "Phone Idle" and "Cell Standby". Let's assume the battery level at that point is 80%, then each app had consumed about 10% of a full charge -- which could count as "normal". If on the other hand the battery level was 20% (or even less), it would be a bad sign -- pointing a.o. to bad reception (see: [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29447/)) for the "Cell Standby" part.

I wrote we already have a lot of good answers on the "battery life" topic. Some are even listed in the "Related" (and now also in the "Linked") section of this question, as e.g.

- [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/)
- [Is there any study on how which services/sensors consume the battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/)

Many more can be found following the tag-link [battery-life](/questions/tagged/battery-life). Please follow those links for closer information.

As the "battery info" is giving you so few information, here's a hint to some helpful app: [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats). With that app, watch out especially for the "Wake Locks", as those keep your device from entering energy-saving modes. Check the configuration of the apps mentioned in connection with this (a good example could be an email app with a too-high polling frequency, where you e.g. could reduce the frequency from "every 5 minutes" to "every 30 minutes" to save a lot of juice).

**EDIT:** Another helpful app I just discovered is [Battery Stats Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.bstats), which helps you find the "evil apps" on your device. Brought to you by our friend at [XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/battery-stats-plus-proactively-detects-battery-draining-apps/)...

Answer (score 1):

I have installed an app called [Battery Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.batteryplus) from the Play Store. It is incredible. Works great on my Android. It really reduces the battery consumption, and I can also kill the unwanted apps running through this app.

Answer (score -1):

I have an Ace and have found a way to have my battery to last for literally days. It is at 50% currently and it has been 51 hours since I last charged it. I just turn off wifi, data transmission etc and at night put it in 'phone mode' and it makes the battery last longer.

Comment: Sure, if you cut the device off all network connections, that saves a lot! Cut off the phone network as well, and the battery will last a week or more. This may be fine for some people, but most bought a smartphone since they want to use its capabilities. However, putting it to airplane mode at night (when you do not intend to use it) might be fine for most people. But then, you also cut connect the charger at night as well... Moreover: How does that apply to the question? Here it's clearly not the data, but the cell network causing trouble.