# How to have a long Standby and Battery -life?

Tags: battery, standby, dual-sim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device)

My Huawei Android is dead after one day. I am looking for

1. ways to extend the battery life
2. a new Android -phone with long battery-life (3. hopefully a phone with two Sim -cards)

I don't know what I really need. For 1, the Wifi/3D-all-the-time-on eats battery -- but hey I like to read my emails on phone. For 2, I could buy more bulky phone. For 3, something [here](http://www.lightinthebox.com/narrow/dual-sim_v17829t0/android-phone_v20320t0/cell-phones_c206) (not sure about the quality). Look I currently use my non-3G iPad with long battery -life, I could buy the 3G version to alleviate the battery problem. I also use Nokia 9300 or Nokia 1111 with 1 week battery life.

With Wifi/3G -problem, is it possible to have them in some energy -saving mode. 1 day battery in Android phones is totally ridiculous. How can I get long battery life?

Comment: Your second question is off-topic; shopping recommendations are not on-topic here. (Please read the [FAQ].) As for your first question, there are multiple questions here that cover eking more life out of a battery. I hate to tell you that a smartphone that lasts an entire day without needing recharging is doing well. Two days is pretty much unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this two parts of your question:

> ...ways to extend the battery life...
>
> ...With Wifi/3G -problem, is it possible to have them in some energy -saving mode...

I own a Huawei U8510-1 (Android 2.3.4 Gingerbread) and I also had to deal with that battery issue. When I've bought it, my battery lasted a day, forcing me to recharge it every night.

After some tests, by disabling and enabling stuff, I was able to give it a slight increase, specially when I've disabled the 3G, leaving only the WiFi.
, but couldn't get it to pass two days without a recharge.

The best solution I've found till the present day was this APP:

- [Easy Battery Saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.millennium.ncl.batterysaver) *free*

  > Save power, extend battery life and perfect experience of using phone with Easy Battery Saver!

It works and really makes a difference. I'm able to control every small detail regarding what my phone should or shouldn't be doing, down to what apps can use 3G or WiFi. Now I charge my phone one, max two times a week, depending on the usage. :)