# Android limited to 1 hour video recording?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, video, file-system, video-recording

At the moment, I am using the standard video recording app for video recording.  I have found that the recording automatically stops after just 1 hour.  Is this a deliberate limitation placed on the app, or is this an android limitation?

I have a 32Gb sd-card, so I don't think storage is a problem.  I am using Android 2.2.  I understand that this particular version of android has a 2.1Gb file size limit, but the videos I am recording are no where near 2.1Gb in file size.

So what is causing the video to stop after just one hour is my real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most video recording apps are IMHO limited to 1h non-stop recording, as you can find with a simple [Google search](http://www.google.de/search?q=android+%22video+recording%22+time+limit), which is probably a safety measure to not let you run out of battery -- as video recording is the biggest consumer (see [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device/27742#27742)).

However, a developer can have his app overriding this limit (see [Max duration for capture video on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853783/max-duration-for-capture-video-on-android) on Stack Overflow) -- so you might just have to find a video recording app which has this setting increased (as e.g. [One Eye Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snugsoftware.oneeyer) in this linked pro-version).

Comment: There's also a EU tax regulation that classifies devices with >=30min recording capabilities as video cameras, maybe this is also a reason here? (source on [dpreview](http://www.dpreview.com/news/2012/05/18/WTO-looking-at-moves-to-remove-30-minute-limit-from-digital-cameras) and [photo.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14563/why-is-there-a-limit-restriction-to-the-1080p-film-video-recording-time-duration))

Comment: That wouldn't explain a limit of 59:59 -- but AFAIK the Droid was limited to 29:59, which would be explained by that.