# Is there an app or setting available to increase video recording duration?

Tags: video-recording

My question is similar, but not identical to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/android-limited-to-1-hour-video-recording). Essentially I'd like to record videos of unlimited length on my android device(s) - that prior question seems to deal with a technical limitation: max filesize for FAT32. My issue is with an arbitrary limitation: the GNex uses EXT4 so max filesize isn't a reason to cut off my recordings at 30 minutes so I can only assume that this limit must be hard-coded into either the camera app or Android itself.

I understand that for many users you need to do some hand-holding and keep them from sucking down battery life, but I intend to record on a tripod while plugged in so none of that really matters to me. I'm also aware of an antiquated tax act in parts of Europe that heavily taxes devices that can record for > 30 minutes as "video recording devices" but I don't live in Europe and don't want to be limited by the obscure tax code of a country I don't even live in.

Is there a way to disable this limitation so the built-in camera app can record for > 30 minutes? Is there some alternate video recording app that doesn't have this limitation? Do the answers to these questions change if I root my phone?

Comment: I've read that question some time ago, and yes: there were two apps mentioned not having this limitation. Just need to find the source again...

Comment: See [Android limited to 1 hour video recording?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/16575) -- there it is! I ***LOVE*** our search function! :D (try: "[video-recording] limit")

Comment: Except that there isn't any real answer there and the question is so old it's referencing Froyo. The "One Eye Browser" app linked actually has an even shorter 10 minute limitation as opposed to recording for longer and no actual suggestion to fix the problem was made.

Comment: P.S. I know how to type words in a search box. That question references an ancient version and an arbitrary filesize limitation that a GNex on 4.11 with an EXT4 filesystem no longer has.

Comment: Why was this closed as a duplicate? The referenced question, as I've stated, is speaking of a filesize-based limitation because of the format of that user's SD card and old Android version, this is not a limitation based on file size, partition type or version as that question is. This is an issue of an arbitrarily placed limitation hard-coded into either Android itself or the camera app. The answer on that previous question isn't helpful and doesn't apply to this scenario.

Comment: when you explained that, the question already had some close-votes (we unfortunately cannot withdraw once we've voted). I guess the other voter(s) may have missed the comment. Suggestion: Edit your question and add the fact you know about the other question, plus explain why that's *not* a duplicate. That should trigger the re-open process and, enough votes provided, re-open your question. Besides: the usual way in this case is not to simply create a new question, but to place a bounty to the original one "for update" ;)

Comment: I'll edit. I don't want to put a bounty on a question which, if answered, still wouldn't solve my problem. That question deals with a technical limitation, this is an arbitrary one :P

Comment: Where did you get this *I'm also aware of an antiquated tax act in parts of Europe that heavily taxes devices that can record for > 30 minutes as "video recording devices" but I don't live in Europe and don't want to be limited by the obscure tax code of a country I don't even live in.*? Never heard of it and that's a new one to me!

Comment: @DavidPerry Understandable. Just wanted you to *consider* ;) With your edit, it entered the re-open queue (2 votes now, so good chances). I would also be interested in the answer to t0mm13b's question: If that's true, we have a big problem. There are cams and dvd/blueray/harddisk recorders capable of much more than 30min, sold freely here in Europe.

Comment: @t0mm13b I got it from an [article](http://www.dpreview.com/news/2012/05/18/WTO-looking-at-moves-to-remove-30-minute-limit-from-digital-cameras) last year discussing an attempt to repeal it. Looking back at the article it might actually be an import tariff rather than a tax. It's not just Android either, a lot of still-frame cameras won't shoot more than 30 for the same reason. Still, Android is the open platform, right? If I wanted some 3rd party telling me how long my vids could be I'd buy an iPhone (which AFAIK can actually record ~50 minutes before its filesystem gives up the ghost)

Comment: I honestly find *that* incredulous... will dig up the Android sources for GB/ICS and JB and see if there's a time limit built in and get back on this - am intrigued and admittedly gob-smacked by that 30 min restriction which places **nearly** every manufacturer's camera within their smart-phone device, in that category classified as "video-recorder" if that is true!!!!

Comment: BTW OP - what device are you referring to?

Comment: @t0mm13b my bad, thought I'd posted it somewhere in all this mess. Samsung Galaxy Nexus - the Verizon version if that matters (it's surprising how often that matters).

Comment: @t0mm13b, a quick search on the web "30 minute limit on video capture" produced more mentions of this issue. It has to do something with the definition of a "video camera". So as far as I understood from reading other articles, if a device is able to record videos of lengths more than 29 min 59 seconds it is considered a video camera

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Magisto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magisto). I just tested it initially and managed to record for almost 2.5 hours before I stopped it.

Comment: Lots of comments saying it's paid to use all features now (2019). Any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

open camera has done the job for me. https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=opencamera&fdid=net.sourceforge.opencamera