# Is there a hardware or software limitation to how long smartphone can record video?

Tags: hardware, video-recording

Besides the obvious battery and storage limitations, are there any limits to how long can a smartphone record video? For example, could the image sensor overheat after an hour or more? Would the camera software explode?

Comment: Related: [Android limited to 1 hour video recording?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28395/16575) / [Is there an app or setting available to increase video recording duration?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39565/16575)

Answer (score 2):

In theory no limit on recording. But as you say overheading is a big problem on summar days.

I experience that camera did shutted down recording video because a software problem. When you recorded, everyframe have to processed by processor. And camera recording process is a stream between processor and camera chip. During this stream, if a bit of stream's data changes, processor will handle an error in stream and will delete all recorded stream. This is a one scenario. Scenario's count can be increased.

For example if processor heat up, and after heating up , on transistor level will one electricity jump 1001st transistor to 1002th transistor and this cause a processor error and this can be the limit of recording video.

I hope I could explain.

Comment: You forgot about file system limitations. Depending on the file system used, limits differ – but the size of a single file cannot exceed a certain number. Of course, an app could take care for that by splitting recordings to multiple files, but not all video recording apps do. Plus, if I remember correctly, there were some legal/licensing issues.

Comment: He says ignore the obvious battery and storage limitations.

Comment: You're correct, and I was not critisizing (just adding "the obvious"). Count it as a "note for other interested readers" ;)