# Hey I have a moto g and I can't record longer then 3 mins

Tags: camera

If you can help me I have a Motorola G and I don't get paid often enough to worry about buying a actual camera and I like to record stuff with friends and I no matter what I try I can't record longer the 3 minutes now I've played around with settings and my video thing is on 720p and I still can't figure out what to do if you can help please do

Comment: Where are you saving? If it is external SD it should be formatted to `ext` as `FAT 32` has a 4 GB limitation on file size// also see if there is a *security lock Timer* or some such setting that is set to 3 minutes

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just saves to the phone idk how to save it to anything else

Comment: Try the app [mentioned here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/45156)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the video size in the camera settings to something lower? and there should be an option to set the storage location. The amount to recording time that will fit on the memory will depend on the size of that memory and the resolution settings you select for the camera.

*To determine how much time a memory will hold, multiply its size by the number of minutes for the settings you set then divide that number by 60 to determine the number of hours*. -

*Exemple: 16GB SD card X 15 minutes per GB (720p @30fps on High resolution) = 240 min.*