# Is it possible to write video directly to external device while recording

Tags: video

I have a Nexus 5 that I'd like to use for some video recording. The meetings I'd like to record are likely to run long enough that they might cause my phone to run out of space mid-recording. I am wondering whether it is possible to connect my phone to my Macbook (or some other device) such that the file is written directly to my Macbook SSD while recording; in other words, to use the phone as a peripheral. Is this possible?

Comment: There is a limitation in-built, (not just confined to  Android, its also present on Apple as well), think its maximum 30 minutes for recording. Something to do with video copyright, IIRC, it was mentioned here on this very site a good while ago.

Comment: Check [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/android-limited-to-1-hour-video-recording) It was not to do with copyright, rather, if it recorded longer than max time, it would be classified as video recorder and not a phone.

Comment: There might be possibilities to facilitate the recorders "preview mode", and transmitting it via HDMI (screen mirroring). This is just a raw idea, I don't know whether such solutions already exist. I also don't know about sound in such cases.

Comment: You can use IP webcam apps on Play Store and turn your mobile into a webcam and record the video screen in your PC using a video recording software. This requires an USB cable or your mobile and computer connected to the same network.

Comment: @Lucky That's a solid answer, if you post it as an answer rather than comment I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can use [IP webcam apps on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ip%20webcam&c=apps&hl=en) and then turn your mobile easily into a webcam and record your computer's screen using a video recording software. This way you can rely on your computer's memory instead of your mobile's storage(which is limited in most cases). Now you can use your phone as a webcam peripheral device and recording videos directly in your Macbook's SSD storage. Some apps provide functions to add a server and upload the videos to cloud.

***Note***: Most app requires an USB cable connection or that you have your mobile and computer connected to the same network which is why it named IP webcam since it is accessed using the IP address generated from the connected network.

Comment: +1, and I wonder [why  didn't it click me before](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/111451/96277). Though the issue is that compared to original quality of the video, you would be limited to the quality displayed on the screen.

Comment: @Firelord Oh Yes, The quality is one factor which was not great for two-three apps that I used before under the tag [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ip%20webcam&c=apps&hl=en) in playstore. But since I recorded the videos with my front cam which is 1.8MP i can't expect much quality. I'm sure a phone with better camera quality can provide you with good quality video outputs. ;)