# Transferring continuous Android camera feed to PC through USB (in a background app/service)

Tags: camera, background-process

I want to find a way in which I can continuously send the Android camera feed to my PC via USB. The reason for specifying USB, is because of performance requirements, I want it to be as fast as possible, hence preferring USB over Wifi. I need the app to be running in the background (will be a service I believe).

I tried some existing apps, but they do not meet my requirements.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Ok, will do so.

Comment: IP Webcam does work on USB but on tethering. App won't shows the address but you can access it at `192.168.42.1:8080` I just confirmed it.

Comment: I see, I will check it thanks. Please post it as answer, else I can't upvote.

Comment: Sorry! The URL is `192.168.42.129:8080`. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en)(see [revisions](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/111443/revisions)) does allow the access on USB but it will not show you the option to access in its help section. All you've to do is activate USB-tethering on your device, start server on the said app,and access the server by entering `192.168.42.129:8080` in a browser on PC.

I tested this app on my device running Android 4.2.1.

Comment: Doesn't the IP address change everytime dynamically? Some of the apps that I used generated the ip-address on-the-fly after opening the app. But I was using the Wi-Fi network instead. So I'm not sure if this is same on the usb-tethering access too.

Comment: @Lucky As you would be knowing that these apps runs a server for their cause, and in case of USB/Wifi tethering the default gateway i.e. `192.168.42.129/192.168.43.1` will remain same every time. Since the app isn't bind to a specific network interface, you can always rely upon the IP address I mentioned provided that the device is tethered.

Comment: Ah! I din't know that before. Its the same way a webserver's default address is started at 127.0.0.1/192.168.0.1 sometimes known as localhost. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

IP Webcam has severe lag even when USB tethered.
Because internet protocol is still used in this setup. 
Dial down the video settings and disable audio capture from phone
This made the lag 'tolerable' for me.

Thanks.