# Do battery saver apps really work? Is it possible to save battery programmatically?

Tags: battery-life

There are [numerous apps in the Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=battery+saver&c=apps) claiming to double or triple the battery life. Is it just a myth? Or can they really?

If they really do save some power, why doesn't Android do it by default?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those battery saver apps probably work by killing tasks, lowering brightness, disabling data or internet connection, and several other things. Those little things will definitely save battery one way or another.

Why doesn't Android do it by default? *I don't know*; you'd have to ask the Android developers that. If Android did what battery saver apps do, they'd be limiting Android. Who wants their screens to always be in low brightness? Or their internet connection off when not in use? Those things are probably better off for people to decide, and battery apps (and other relatated apps or utilities) will help them do that.

See also this post on improving battery life: [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device)

Answer (score 2):

Battery saver apps are useless.You can save battery life by manually reducing brightness ,screen time out,back light duration or turning off the data, GPS, wi fi,blue tooth,etc from settings. There is no need for an app to do it. These apps actually take more power out of your device. So I think Android does not need a battery saving app.

Answer (score -3):

Believe it or not. THEY DO NOTING BUT SHOWING ADVERTISEMENT and ultimately consuming more battery. They will present an animation showing the list of the apps they are closing for us. But they do nothing. The proof is, just go to  the app manager and check app info, all those apps are running in background.

Comment: "*But they do nothing.*" -- that's quite a bold claim. Greenify also runs in the background but works superb. Consider backing up your claim with technical sources or in-depth details.