# Does Cyanogenmod reduce battery life?

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery-life

My galaxy mini was running GB 2.3.6. I recently rooted my phone and installed CM 7.2. Now it looks like my battery is getting drained a little quicker than before. From what I have heard CM increases performance while giving a better battery life. So is my case an exception? Can somebody suggest methods to increase battery life after installing Cyanogenmod?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device)

Comment: [It definitely does on some devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70132/atrocious-battery-life-with-cyanogenmod-10-2-on-galaxy-s4-mini).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two reasons why a CM ROM might reduce battery life:

1. CPU governor:
   The cpu governor controls the frequency of the CPU depending on the requirement. Your ROM might be using a governor that favours performance over battery life. Selecting a governor that achieves a good balance between performance & battery life might help you. You can learn more about cpu governors [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1856256)
2. Battery calibration: 
   The battery status is stored in a file called batterystats.bin. Its possible that your phone is using the same batterystats.bin that came with the rom. You can use an application like [Battery Calibration](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5uZW1hLmJhdHRlcnljYWxpYnJhdGlvbiJd) to regenerate this file with new/accurate stats.(a [myth according to this](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/google-engineer-debunks-myth-wiping-battery-stats-does-not-improve-battery-life/))

Answer (score 2):

It Depends. yes, depends on your settings (Auto Brightness, Wifi Scan interval, GPS, Auto Sync Enabled) type of applications installed (Widgets and its high auto refresh rate) and many more (kernel wakelock) etc.

Just try to check what consumes your battery using [better battery stats](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809). From that you can identify, what causing battery drain.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, if you have cyanogen mod installed, no new aps just the rom and you use the phone exactly as you would youse it with your stock rom, yes cyanogen mod will take more battery but at the same time it is more light weight and faster.
So yes cyanogen mod does take up a bit more battery then a stock rom, at least from my experinece with cm.

Comment: Can you give any source for this? On all my phones, my experience always was the other way around: with CM, they were/are smoother running and the battery did last longer (20% increased battery-life was no exception). You cannot generalize it as such: with what do you compare? What you are implying is "any other ROM saves more than CM -- CM is the worst battery eater amongst all the ROMs available". Sounds unbelievable to me :)

Comment: I was comparing it to STOCK rom only. And as Cyborgs mentioned it depends on how you use your phone, but if you compare EXACTLY the same Stock rom with CM, same useage and all you will get a better battery life on stock then cm. and why do you even mention smooth running if you are comparing battery life. i mention to that if you refer just to battery on cm is not that good but you get a lot of other good stuff. I love CM, and it is the only rom I use and recommand but let's face it it will never have same battery as the stock rom does.

Comment: First: I mention *smooth running* as the OP asked for it ("increases performance"). And second: as I wrote, on *all* my devices I used CM on, it performed better and battery life was better as well. But I forgot this was not a *generic* question, but relates to a specific device I never owned -- so your "stock ROM" was a specific one (the stock ROM of this device) as well -- and it was rather *me* who generalized; my apologies for that! Still, it might be a good idea to either give a source -- or at least restrict it "to your experience" ;)

Comment: Ok I will tell you the phones I tested CM on. HTC wildfire,desire hd, Huawei Pulse, xperia s and xperia z the galaxy series except the tabled ones and galaxy note 2. Yes you are right i have generalieze a bit, but i tought since i used it on many models it would be the same for all the others. I am sorry that i have generalized for all devices.

Comment: Strange: the Wildfire was in my repertoire as well. And it got *much* smoother and *much* more battery-saving with CM7. -- but let's stop this here: we are not a discussion forum. I'd still suggest to include a "to my experience" with your answer :)

Comment: "I'd still suggest to include a "to my experience" with your answer" - exactly, because we still don't actually have an answer to the question - just some supposition.

Answer (score 0):

Just for my experience with the Xperia Mini Pro (3 years of use and the new Note 3:
The stock was more efficient in using the battery even it was filled with bloatware.
Same reason why i am looking this up - to go with some stock modified rom or CM which i like more, but battery is a must...

Answer (score 0):

Most of the custom ROMs usually eats little more battery than the pre-installed OS. Cyanogen is optimized ROM, if you have downloaded it from the their official site. Because there are many other developers customizing Cyanogen OS with little more perks and ultimately messing up the performance.

As you have already mentioned, you might have downloaded unofficial CM. Just check the source from where you downloaded.