# Atrocious battery life with Cyanogenmod 11 on Galaxy S4 mini

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I love so many things about CM10, but the battery life is an absolute nightmare. I made a comparison against the stock firmware by leaving the phone unused for as long as I could. Results:

Stock: **~5.2 days standby** to full discharge

CM10: **~1.7 days of standby** to full discharge

**Is there anything I can do about this, or is CM10 simply not supported properly on my device?**

---

Made these screenshots on my S4 mini by leaving it unused for as long as I could. In the CM10 example it actually powered off due to low battery and I had to plug it in before it would even turn on again, so this is NOT due to any calibration; the battery was *actually* empty at the end of the test. But even if you take the final charge as 15%, the numbers are still atrocious.

[image]

Comment: Clearly it states in the screenshots that mobile standby uses the most power, possibly even wakelocks. Are you leaving it on 3G/4G/LTE without a mobile data connection?

Comment: @aureljared 3G and Wi-Fi were permanently enabled in both cases. The phone was in exactly the same location: my house.

Comment: CM11 did not improve things; BetterBatteryStats doesn't show any significant wakelocks either... A real mystery. Glad to know [I'm](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/354484-cm11-very-fast-battery-drain.html) [not](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/435254-cm11-battery-life.html) [the](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/85397-terrible-battery-life-on-cm-11/) [only](http://www.reddit.com/r/cyanogenmod/comments/2awrmb/cm11_m8_release_high_battery_drain/) [one](http://www.reddit.com/r/cyanogenmod/comments/22mxb3/cm11_s3_short_battery_life/).

Answer (score 2):

These are the settings I use on my phone, which have helped with the power consumption.

Under Performance

-> Processor

- CPU governer: ONDEMAND

-> Profile

- Power save

General Settings page

-> Location Services: off

-> Bluetooth off

-> Mobile Data (3g): off

There are also some apps that may be helpful, one of which (I've only heard of it not actually used) is called SnapDragon Battery Guru.

If you can't find the performance settings turn on developer options (instructions [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc%3a_developer_options))

Answer (score 1):

Calibration needs to be done after flashing a new ROM.
I've solved this problem by using "Battery Calibration" app from the Play store.

http://zoranpetrovic87.blogspot.com/2014/10/cyagenmod-battery-problem.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm now on CM11 and battery life remains a constant struggle. There are just too many things that will happily keep the phone awake, almost always due to bugs or incompatibilities. You're lucky when it's just a bad app you've installed: kill it and the problem is gone. But far too often, the thing keeping your phone away is Google Play Services, and then you're basically stuffed.

So my best advice is to simply decide whether a constant battery life problem is worth CM's improvements (it is for me, but it might not be for you).

You should also expect that whenever you do manage to track down and fix a battery life killer, it won't be a week before something else crops up. Just recently I had finally found an amazing fix that made my phone *actually enter sleep*, and it was to set Wi-Fi to turn off when the phone is off. I had a few weeks of bliss, but fast forward to a few days ago and [it's back to the usual battery-eating never-sleeping state](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2z5y96/discussion_is_the_new_play_services_7x_presenting/).

So yeah, you will probably experience battery life issues with CM, but I think it's totally worth it.