# How to disable/remove ALL cell functionality

Tags: battery, battery-life, streaming, cellular-radio

I have a Kyocera Event (Virgin Mobile) running stock Android 4.0.4.

This is only used as a media player for about 90 minutes ONE DAY per week. I am looking for a good way to extend battery life as much as possible as it can only be charged one day a week as well.

Steps taken:

- Disabled google account sync
- Turned off all location services
- Turned "Mobile Data" off

I know it's asking a lot, but I am really hoping to get the battery to last a week if possible.

Any suggestions for extending battery life?

Comment: Hot tip: our [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info), with links to e.g. [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/16575) and similar questions. Also, some more details might help: Do you need any SIM activity (calls etc.) at all? If so: no chance for 1+ week. Do you have root access on the device? That gives additional possibilities like underclocking, greenifying, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with just turning it off for the other six days?

Comment: @DanHulme There is a buggy app in use that loses it's configuration if the app gets closed. The users have very limited tech skills and I am hoping to not have to train them to configure this program every time they need it.