# Reduce the screen brightness below given permissible level

Tags: screen, screen-brightness

Is it possible to reduce the screen brightness below given level? Well if possible does it really reduce the energy consumption.

Comment: That programming part would make this question off-topic (see [help/on-topic] to know more). I suggest you remove it. // By given level, do you mean the level set by your OEM? If that's the case, then yes, you can reduce it.

Comment: I suppose this is what you're looking for: [How can I reduce screen brightness below the minimum without an app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44270)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to reduce the brightness level below the default screen brightness slider level. You can use, [Night Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.bbarao.nightmode) app from Play Store.

As mentioned in the app description,

> Night Mode's main goal is to reduce the brightness of your screen
>   lower than you can achieve with the default settings.

And this app doesn't require you a root permission.

Does this setting saves battery?

It depends upon the screen you have for your phone. If you have AMOLED screen it will save battery for you.

See this post for more explanation [How does reducing brightness of screen increase battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/82313/27149)

Comment: Figuratively, it does, because it uses overlay filter so it would feel that brightness is reduced, though energy consumption isn't reduced on my screen. Technically, it doesn't.

Comment: Updated my answer. In AMOLED screens it will reduce the battery consumption based on [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/82314/27149) post.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that, so changed my comment to "my screen". :)