# Does using brightness dimmer (screen filter) really save battery?

Tags: applications, command-line, screen-brightness

We know that the lower the scree light/brightness, the lower the battery consumption.

There are some applications which provide ability (without root) to lower the brightness beyond the (default) limit.

So, I want to know does it really save battery? In other words, does it affect battery consumption comparatively to default minimum limit?

Btw, I'm also interested to know *how does such application do this task if going beyond limit?*

And is there any command-tool related to settings brightness level?

Comment: That's answered as part of the issue here: [How does reducing brightness of screen increase battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/82313/16575) Quoting: *Using a software overlay to darken pixels on an LCD screen won't reduce the power consumption.* Summing up: Depends on the display type. On an AmoLED, it might have effect. See the linked posts for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does reducing brightness of screen increase battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82313/how-does-reducing-brightness-of-screen-increase-battery-life)

Answer (score 0):

When you decrease the brightness of a light, it normally means less power is consumed. Therefore, having a lower screen brightness than your default would suggest battery use is reduced further than normal.

As far as I can guess, the screen brightness will just be a command in the android system that changes power flow through the screen LED's. The phone manufacturers likely just set their brightness slider's lowest value to whatever arbitrary value they expect a standard user would require. The app's that you are using just influences the same function, but drops the power lower.

*e.g.* 
*Samsung use a minimum screen brightness of 30% power, but your app will drop to 10%*

I don't know the specifics of such tool.