# How to save battery on Moto G 2nd generation without installing third party apps?

Tags: battery, motorola

How do I save battery life on my Moto G 2nd generation phone without installing third party apps ?

Comment: Same as on other devices. See our [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info) for hints, and especially follow up to [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/16575)

Comment: @Izzy I took a look at your provided link, that did not work for me

Comment: I didn't mark it duplicate :) Most items are general, here and on the other question as well. And what's general, answers this and the other question :)

Comment: @Izzy I just included the common points along with the points specific to this phone type.

Comment: Droidzer, I was not critisising – just providing related information. Up to now, I didn't realize you're the OP and answerer at the same time, or I had phrased it differently :) But apart from that: many points are named in both places. Your answer had fit over there as well, as it adds some minors (keypad tones, volume, pulse notification – they don't do much, but they contribute their part).

Comment: @Izzy Well the below points worked out for me well. So thought by posting this other people having this type of the phone would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save battery without installing third party apps here are a few tips,

- Disable vibration on your phone for notifications, calls, keypads.
- Disable keypad tones.
- Turn off Automatic screen rotation.
- If you prefer to keep your phone silent during night, better switch it to Airplane mode, this will save a lot of battery.
- Keep your phones brightness to a minimum.(Disable auto brightness option.)
- Keep your phones volume low.
- Turn off mobile data when not in use.
- Disable background data on mobile networks for specific apps which consume unnecessary. To do this navigate to Settings - > Data Usage, there you will find the list of apps that consume the data, click on the app and then select "Restrict background Data".
- Disable the pulse notification light. Go to Settings - > Display and uncheck the option Pulse notification light.