# Samsung S3 neo battery life started to reduce rapidly from 2 days

Tags: battery-life

I am using a galaxy s3 neo phone from almost 8 months, from two days I was using my computer internet in my mobile through usb. Then yesterday night while sleeping the battery was 47 percentage , and morning when I got up and used my phone it got off because of low battery. I dint face this problem from past 8 months, but from two days the battery is reducing a lot even if I am using or not using. Please can anyone say what measures should I take to make my battery as normal???

Thank you in advance

Comment: related: [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device)

Comment: Try to calibrate your battery, after a lot of discharge cycles it is probable to face these problems