# Battery quickly discharged after installation of Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery-life, tablet, bugs

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5. Recently I've updated it to Lollipop 5.0.2 through Odin. Then problem with battery have arisen: charge falls on one percent each three minutes when brightness is medium, 3G is on, screen is always on and music is enabled.

Does this problem really relate to possible confrontation with Lollipop?

Comment: Go through some answers related to battery life and Lollipop. Check the battery usage of applications in power management. If everything is okay then it's time to change the battery.

Comment: You can look into which specific app consumes more battery in the Settings-> Battery or you could post the screenshot of the image graph in this question

Comment: @MANI : it's in usage only for two months.

Comment: @John You could have mentioned that in the question itself :) Have you checked battery usage?

Comment: @Lucky and to MANI: battery usage is normal - the most intensive battery exploiter is display, while the other components (OS, applications) use charge significantly lower.  Now I think that the deal is in the fact that after each installation of new Android OS I have to calibrate the battery. May it correspond to the possible solution of the problem?

Comment: @JohnTaylor since the screen is big for tablets it will consume battery heavily even if it is configured to lowest brightness settings..i think a fully charged tablet drains the whole battery in 5-6 hrs in normall usage..so i guess your tab with screen on forever should give you 2-3hrs which is normal considering your usage..

Comment: also you may want to try these to increase the battery life..http://android.stackexchange.com/a/478/27149

Comment: @JohnTaylor - Music is ON, 3G is ON, Display brightness at medium and is always ON - so battery is normal and healthy because it is a tablet first of all.