# Moto g 2 Battery is draining within 3 hours

Tags: battery

My motog 2 is draining the battery drastically as fast as it can. Please help me. I couldn't carry a charger all the tym. I have consulted the customer care service they provided me two links to reboot and reset the settings. But it doesn't works. Help me
thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device).

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You didn't provide enough details to enable us helping you. The device certainly doesn't drain the battery by itself while being switched off (oops). So what are you doing within those 3 hours? Have you installed a lot of apps? Changed some settings? And, most importantly, have you checked what the top consumers are (you can do so in *Settings › Battery*; a screenshot of that would be helpful here)?

Answer (score 0):

Battery draining is common problem and there are various solutions and guides found by little searching I can give a few pointers that may help.

Disable location from Google Settings, disable all connections you are not using(Bluetooth, GPS, NFC etc.)

Check from battery monitor(Settings) which application or service is draining the battery most. Disable unnecessary aplications from Settings>Applications>All>Select an app>Disable. Also disable unused account synchronizations under Settings -> Accounts -> Turn off Sync.

There are also good third-party applications for monitoring battery statistics as for example [GSam battery monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm) 
and for saving battery use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify)

Further information can be found on [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/).

Comment: I would add one more thing, do not forget to calibrate the battery. All of the suggestions in the answer worked well only after calibration in my case.