# How to improve battery lasting in Android?

Tags: battery-life

I know the thread [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/9897) which is a subset of this question. 
I want to understand how you can improve battery lasting in Android, which is a much broader topic than the original.
I am especially interested in Android versions later than 4.4 because of [Xposed installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), a necessity of [Greenify's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) applications, is developed for those versions but still in the experimental phase.

I see this after morning use in Samsung Galaxy 4 and Android 5.0.1:

[image: Screenshot]

which is too fast. I am using battery saving mode and disabled step-counter from my phone.

How can you use better battery in Android?

Comment: Also see: [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/476/16575) – and our [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info) :)

Comment: Thank you for the link! The thread is minimalist about this thread. It is about what, while mine is about how. I want to understand how to improve my battery lasting, since I have not bee able to do it with those "what answers".

Comment: Isn't "how" the "practicing of what"? :confused:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase you battery lasting by making this settings on your phone:

- Go to settings-> Battery, check which app is consuming your battery, you have to get rid of that.
- You should off the unnecessary hardware radio's [wifi, bluetooth, Internet], if you are not using it like at night.
- Turn off the app services which are not useful, by going to settings->apps.
- Remove if any live wallpaper or widget you had used on home screen.
- Turn down the brightness and turn off Automatic Brightness.
- Update your apps.
- Put the device on Airplane mode if you are not using it like on Flight.
- Use power control app or other battery saver app.
- You can use Greenify app that can really help you in saving battery life.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Greenify doesn't need root anymore for hibernating user apps - just fyi

Comment: Excellent answer! Many improvements, I could do. I will wait for improvements in Xposed environment for Greenify because it is still environmental. It has many good ideas which can significantly improve the battery lasting.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a rooted device with Xposed Framework installed, you can use [Deep Sleep Battery Saver](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.rootuninstaller.batrsaver). It works better than many others because it has the ability to hook into the phone and control it directly. But don't install Xposed Framework just for a battery saver.

Answer (score 0):

Follow whatever tips you can do that KMDigital suggested prior to this in case it is an app or apps causing your problem.

Also consider the battery age. Over time batteries become less and less efficient. You can replace your battery with an extended battery as well. It makes your phone heavier as a result, but your battery time will improve significantly.

If you do have spotty or no coverage, do use airplane mode, your phone uses more battery when it's searching for a signal or the signal received is low. Also turn off wifi when you don't need to use it but you expect cell coverage instead of airplane mode.