# Can I charge Galaxy Tab S2 while using MHL adapter?

Tags: samsung, charging, mhl

I'm looking at an [MHL adapter provided by Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/ET-H10FAUWESTA). I have a Galaxy Tab S2 and wonder if this adapter would allow the device to charge up at the same time as mirroring the screen to my TV.

I already have a [multi-use adapter with MHL + SD + USB](http://amzn.com/B00KW4MKMU). Unfortunately, connecting micro-USB power to the multi-use adapter does not charge the tablet.

I would like to know if I can charge the device at the same time as using the HDMI connection.

Anyone know if this works?

Answer (score 1):

The [Galaxy Tab S2 (2016, 9.7, Wi-Fi) specs](http://www.samsung.com/uk/tablets/galaxy-tab-s2-9-7-t813/SM-T813NZKEBTU/) say that there is no MHL support.

(Which exact device version do you have? Have you tested MHL support in the meantime?)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if I can charge the device at the same time as using the HDMI connection

Theoretically **yes** but practically wouldn't help {see *edit* below)

- Adapter uses [MHL 2 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link) which provides **5 V DC/900 mA**, same as USB 3.0

Further, it says

> MHL passive cable
>
> Passive cables allow consumers to connect an MHL-enabled device directly to an MHL TV and do not require external power. Unlike older MHL adapters and cables, the passive cable simultaneously charges the cell phone battery while mirroring.

- A typical mobile battery charging (without using *fast charging*) for a capacity of 3000 mAh requires around 1800 mAh
- [Galaxy Tab S2](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=UKbuVsfAA8qJ8QeDirfwCw#q=galaxy+tab+s2+battery+life) has a battery that is either 4000/5870 mAh (depending on the model), which is much more than a normal cell, and it would take real long to charge. It would take 10 / 14 hours respectively (To estimate charging time required , use the [Battery Charge Time Calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/batterychgcalc.html))

**Note:** This is based only on the power calculations part of it. I haven't used MHL / HDMI

**Edit:** With reference to your [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145855/can-i-charge-galaxy-tab-s2-while-using-mhl-adapter/145862?noredirect=1#comment188498_145862), if the screen is in use, the power it would draw in *all likelihood* would be more than charging, so in effect, it wouldn't help at all. See this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27742/131553) to get an idea of power used in *screen on* condition

Comment: *"it would take real long to charge"* In my case the goal is to avoid running out of battery life during normal use. I think that the 'typical' charging would be sufficient. I can see how I might need 'fast charging' were I to use Street Navigation + Music, or 3D Gaming, etc.