# consuemd power for Android phones in adhoc mode

Tags: wi-fi, battery, battery-life, ad-hoc-networks, power-options

I want to know the following information:

1-The consumed power by the smartphone when send/receive beacons when connecting with other device in adhoc mode.

2-Is the consumed power is the same for all kind of smartphones?

I tried to search for the required information, but I didn't find a clear answer, I found some general information such as the consumed power when wifi is on.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27742/16575). And yes, it is hardware specific :)