# What is the standard operational battery temperature for the Note 9?

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-note-9

Bought the phone a week ago & today it seems to be running slightly warm just surfing sites in Chrome. Downloaded a battery app and see that the battery temp is at 32 degrees Celsius constantly right now for the last 2 hrs. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

OEMs hardly provide such data to decide if it is normal or not. Not surprisingly, user manual of your device is quiet on this point.

This post on [SE. Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/262917/90246) (talks of Samsung), puts maximum safe temperature as 45°C.

However, temperature has a bearing on the battery performance. See [this](https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/discharging_at_high_and_low_temperatures) for details. At 32°C it results in 80% of optimum battery capacity.

I would consider based on my observations, that this perfectly fine, though Samsung phones have been reported to have  [fast charging problems](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=temperature+too+low+samsung&ia=web) with a low temperature error, which doesn't seem to be your problem.

Comment: what battery temp number would be a concern and definitely needs repair? strangely enough playing mc5 game for an hour for a whole week with no warm back cover. only today it ran warmer though i ran the exact same apps etc

Comment: 45°C. See edit to answer

Comment: good links. i think only once have i had a phone get too hot to even hold: it was my S8 uploading 20GB of files to my new phone. any way to keep heat down while uploading files?

Comment: No. For the simple reason that power is drawn heavily while uploading that leads to high battery temperature. Power drawn varies with device but you can get an idea from [Izzy's answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27742/131553)

Comment: next time i need to use an app that has a pause feature while uploading so the phone can take a break. was using Send Anywhere.