# How can the battery get discharged while Ampere is showing that it is charging?

Tags: battery, android-10

How can the battery get discharged while [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere&hl=en_US&gl=US) is showing that it is charging?

Example:

At 1:06 PM, the battery indicates `2%`.

[image]

At 1:08 PM, the battery indicates `1%`, even though Ampere says that the min mA was strictly positive (`40 mA`).

[image]

How is that possible?

I use Android 10 on Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: Consumption is higher. Try AccuBattery app. It shows realtime (whatever that means) reduction of charge from the battery in a sticky notification. If that is higher than what is reported in Ampere, you have a net reduction in battery charge even during charging. Most likely, USB cable or charger or the usb port of your device is faulty.

Comment: You didn't say what your device was doing at the time, apart from charging, or how much your AC charger is "giving". As for consumption, see my [oder answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27742/16575) for some example values. If you eg record a HD video, stream it live while having the display on full brightness, that means about 4W being consumed. Having an USB2.0 charger connected, you'd only get about 2.5W in (500mA at 5V) – and thus would consume 1.5W more than you feed. Just to give an example.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I has assumed, apparently wrongly, that Ampere would subtract the consumption from the displayed charging speed

Comment: nevertheless you are using wrong cable. buy another cable with 200 Ω resistor on data pins to let usb charging protocol allow fast charging
 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/177788

Comment: @Robert thanks for your edit, but please don't reduce the image resolution when changing the size of the displayed image.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the issue is that Ampere doesn't take into account the battery consumption when showing the charging current.

Example:

AccuBattery, which takes into account the battery consumption when showing the charging current:

[image]

Ampere:

[image]