# How can I charge Motorola One normally?

Tags: charging, motorola, android-one

**tl;dr**: *Every setup that I tried so far ends up with "Charging rapidly" or "Charging slowly" on my Motorola One. What kind of charger (or power source) and cable should I use in order to charge this phone at a standard charging pace?*

---

I was always told that to charge phone rapidly / use QC etc. you need:

- correct rather good quality cable,
- proper charger, 2 A at output at minimum.

The thing is that on my Motorola One I am getting "Charging rapidly" even on cheap 0.5 USD cable connected to:

- 1 A charger (which needs 5-6 hours on other phones),
- 2.0 and 2.4 A charger (which charges other phones in about 2-3 hours) and
- 10 A QC 3.0 charger (which charges other phones in about 1+ hour)

Actually my Motorola One is the only mobile device (out of 15+) in my home that reports "charging rapidly" on every of above setup, even on cheap cable and 1.0 A charger (which isn't able to quickly-charge any other device).

On the other hand, when I connect it to a regular (non-QC) USB, I am always getting "charging slowly", even on very new and expensive PCs (which are told to have 1 A on USB) and even on high-quality, QC-ready cables.

So my question is, what is the correct setup to charge Motorola One "normally"? Is it possible at all in case of this device?

<sub>This question is entirely on getting correct setup to charge Motorola One neither quickly nor slowly (if possible). I don't want to discuss here any related issues like "quickly charging doesn't make your battery weaker anymore, so why you're asking, go ahead and quickly charge every time". Please, don't post comments like that. Thank you.</sub>

Comment: Kind of related: [Wattage for charging status (customizable per device model)](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143053/44325)

Comment: When I search for "Motorola One" I only get results for multiple devices like "Motorola One Zoom" or other words after "One". Different devices may use different fast charging technologies, therefore you should exactly name your device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I design a 2A or more power supply for my consumer USB devices?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177788/how-do-i-design-a-2a-or-more-power-supply-for-my-consumer-usb-devices)

Comment: @AndrewT. Truly, related. It clearly defines meanings of "charging rapidly" and "charging slowly", based on wattage (some could even say that my question is a duplicate of that linked one). You could use this information to answer my question (use any cable with 5-7.5W charger). I won't be able to make any use of this answer, because for some weird reason none of my chargers provided any information on power in watts, it delivers. Only output voltage and current. But, the question will truly be answered.

Comment: @Robert Well... I bought it in Poland, titled exactly "Motorola One 4/64GB Dual SIM white". Here is [the link](https://www.x-kom.pl/p/448947-smartfon-telefon-motorola-one-4-64gb-dual-sim-bialy-etui.html) (destination page is in Polish) to the shop and actual model that I purchased. I assume that this is simply "first edition" of Motorola One. When shipping it to the market they didn't know, if this "will hit", whether there will be some other models or continuations and simply didn't care to add it some special _catchy_ name, I suppose.

Comment: @alecxs Not at all, sorry. I don't want to design my own charger! :>

Comment: if you look at the schematics you will see all it takes is some resistores on the data pins to control charging protocol. these do not necessarily have to be inside the cable. some short circuit (dirt / water) could have same effect. it might also possible this devices comes with resistores on pcb charging dock

Comment: @alecxs It is possible that you're getting me all wrong. I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Please, take a look at my last sentence in the question, where I am asking if this is possible at all. Maybe not? Maybe, due to information that Andrew T. shared with us, no matter which cable and charger I'll use, my phone will always report "charging quickly" and when I use USB port for charging -- will always say "charging slowly".

Comment: yes, and i gave you another possible reason why

Comment: pc won't deliver more than 500 mA no matter what charging mode is requested on data pins, that's limitation in usb protocol. see High-power device https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Low-power_and_high-power_devices

Comment: you may find one of these apps helpful https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232920